# Add a class to a-tag with specific ID-link

Tags: jquery, css, class, addition

I am trying to add the CSS-Class "active" to the anchor-tag which has a href-attribute containing the ID which is currently active in the URL. This is my code so far, but I can't get window.location.hash to work.

```
$( "a[href="window.location.hash"]" ).addClass('active');
```

I need your help!

Additionaly I have to remove that class if the "window.location.hash" changes! I forgot about that :(

Comment: Why not add a class too the anchor tag. Then you could select the class and add the class 'active'.

Comment: I like to keep my markup as simple as possible so if I don't need to add additional markup I try to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your code by the following code. All active classes will be removed and the href having current url will be active.

```
$('.active').removeClass('active');
$( "a[href='" + window.location + "']" ).addClass('active');
```

If u want to remove the active class from a specific section use class hierarchy like

```
$('.xyz .active').removeClass('active');
```

Comment: I added my .hash and it worked :) Thank you kundan! But I need to remove this class if the window.location.hash changes. I forgot to mention this in my question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$( "a[href='\\#ID']" ).addClass('active');
```

or

$( "a[href='"+window.location.hash+"']" ).addClass('active');

Comment: I use you second solotuion. Thank you as well, but I have so remove the class again as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you just want to use the :target pseudoclass (no javascript necessary).  You can read about it here - http://css-tricks.com/on-target/

Comment: I indeed used :target to switch between two uls by clicking on the a-tags with the IDs #popular and #latest. But the A-tag is located in a nav-element above the uls (not within). This is why I can't refer to these A-tags with my :target pseudoclass to activate them.